# Press "Save As" button in Internet Explorer using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I can't press button "Save As" using PowerShell. I tried find options "Save without prompt" into internet Explorer Options, but it doesn't exist.
Also tried use this comand, it doesn't work too.
`$wshell = new-object -com wscript.shell`
`$wshell.AppActivate("Internet Explorer")`
`$wshell.sendkeys("{TAB}")`
`$wshell.sendkeys("{Enter}")`
[Download Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xshfj.png)

What can I try to do yet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When we automate IE to download files on websites, there will be download popup windows showing. We can first active the IE window and bring it to front using **AppActivate**, then use **SendKeys** to send keystrokes `Ctrl+S` to save the file.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")

$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible=$true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.example.com/download.html") #change it to your own url
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}
$link=$ie.Document.getElementById("btnDowload") #change it to your own selector
$link.click()

Sleep 5
$ieProc = Get-Process | ? { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.HWND }
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($ieProc.Id) #active IE window
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("%{s}"); #press Ctrl+S to save file
```